# Environmental variables returning undefined for Kubernetes deployment

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, deployment, environment-variables, kubernetes-secrets

I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62354286/reference-to-environmental-variable-in-client-side-with-kubernetes-deployment) similar to this and tried to implement what the answer for this question said: [How to access Kubernetes container environment variables from Next.js application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59071793/how-to-access-kubernetes-container-environment-variables-from-next-js-applicatio)

However, when I still call my environment variables doing `process.env.USERNAME`, I'm still getting undefined back... Am I doing something wrong in my deployment file? Here is a copy of my `deployment.yaml`:

```
metadata:
  namespace: <namespace>
  releaseName: <release name>
  releaseVersion: 1.0.0
  target: <target>
auth:
replicaCount: 1
image:
  repository: '<name of repository is here>'
  pullPolicy: <always>
container:
  multiPorts:
  - containerPort: 443
  name: HTTPS
  protocol: TCP
  - containerPort: 80
  name: HTTP
  protocol: TCP
  env:
  - name: USERNAME
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: my-username
        key: username
  - name: PASSWORD
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: my-password
        key: password
  - name: HOST
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: my-host
        key: host
  volumeMounts:
  - name: config
    mountPath: "/configMap"
    readOnly: true
volume:
  - name: config
    configMap:
      name: environmental-variables
resources:
  requests:
    cpu: 0.25
    memory: 256Mi
  limits:
    cpu: 1
    memory: 1024Mi
variables:
- name: NODE_ENV
  value: <node env value here>
ingress:
  enabled: true
  ingressType: <ingressType>
  applicationType: <application type>
  serviceEndpoint: <endpoint>
  multiPaths:
    - path: /
    - HTTPS
tls: 
  enabled: true
  secretName: <name>
autoscale:
  enabled: false
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 5
  cpuAverageUtilization: 50
  memoryUtilizationValue: 50
annotations:
  ingress:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: <affinity>
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: <cookie-name>
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: <number>
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: <number>
```

I also created a `configMap.yaml` file, although I'm not sure if that's the right way to do this. Here is my `configMap.yaml` file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: environmental-variables
data:
  .env: |
    USERNAME: <username>
    PASSWORD: <password>
    HOST: <host>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Also I'm trying to make my environment variable as Secrets since I don't want to expose any of my variables because it contains sensitive information. I am trying to do this on a Node.js application using Express. Thank you!

EDIT: Here is how the Secrets part looks like in my yaml file

```
secrets:
  - name: environmental-variables
  key: USERNAME
  - name: environmental-variables
  key: PASSWORD
```

How my Secrets yaml file looks like:

```
kind: Secret
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: environmental-variables
  namespace: tda-dev-duck-dev
data:
  USERNAME: <username>
  PASSWORD: <password>
```

Comment: See the pipe character (`|`) in your ConfigMap - that is the indicator to the problem. Basically, your configmap has only 1 entry, with key `.env` and value being a multiline string with USERNAME, PASSWORD etc. To be able to actually mount entries from ConfigMap as env variables, you need to have multiple entries in the configmap's data block, 1 entry per piece of information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After days of figuring out how to use Secrets as an environmental variable, I figured out how to reference it in my nodejs application!

Before I was doing the normal way of calling environmental variables, `process.env.VARIABLE_NAME`, but that did not work for me when I had Secrets as an environment variable. In order to get the value of the variable, I had to do `process.env.ENVIRONMENTAL_VARIABLES_USERNAME` in my Javascript file and that worked for me! Where `ENVIRONMENTAL_VARIABLES` is the `name` and `USERNAME` is the key!

Not sure if this will help anyone else but this is how I managed to access my Secrets in my nodejs application!

Answer (score 2):

You created `ConfigMap` and trying to get value from secret. If you want set value from configmap then update env like following

```
env:
  - name: USERNAME
    valueFrom:
      configMapKeyRef:
        name: environmental-variables # this is ConfigMap Name
        key: USERNAME # this is key in ConfigMap
  - name: PASSWORD
    valueFrom:
      configMapKeyRef:
        name: environmental-variables
        key: PASSWORD
  - name: HOST
    valueFrom:
      configMapKeyRef:
        name: environmental-variables
        key: HOST
```

and update the configmap like following

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: environmental-variables
data:
  USERNAME: <username>
  PASSWORD: <password>
  HOST: <host>
```

To learn how to define container environment variables using ConfigMap data click [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-container-environment-variables-using-configmap-data)

If you want to use secrets as environment variables check [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables)

Comment: Question about Secrets.. What is a Secret and the benefit of using a Secret?

Comment: Also can you access a secret the same way as an environmental variable, i.e. `process.env.*`

Comment: to learn about secret vs configmap check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/36925553/6027873

Comment: yes you can pass the secret as environment variable .. link https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables

Comment: If I wanted to access the secret, I tried to do `process.env.*` but still get undefined - is the way to access it to do `$SECRET_NAME` like it says in the documentation?

Comment: what you tried for secret? can you share your yaml?

Comment: I have tried to access my secret doing `process.env.VARIABLE_NAME` but I get returned `undefinied`. I have edited my question with my yaml file, although my file is a bit different since there are configurations set already -- I did create a Secret yaml file already with all of my variables too