# Access secrets as environment variables in Kubernetes

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, deployment, environment-variables, dotenv

I'm using Secrets as an environmental variable and I was wondering how you would call the secret in the client side of my application? I'm running a Node.js application and want to use the Secrets environmental variable. I would normally call my environment variables by doing `process.env.VARIABLE_NAME` locally since I have an env file, but I know that it's not the same for a secret as environmental variable when deployed onto Kubernetes.

Could anybody help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Environment variables should act the same no matter whether they're set from a literal value, the downward API, a ConfigMap, or a Secret value.  [Distribute Credentials Securely Using Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#define-container-environment-variables-using-secret-data) in the Kubernetes documentation has some examples.  Is there a specific setup you're having trouble with?

Comment: I see.. so if I do `process.env.*` to access my environmental variable that is a Secret, it should work the same way then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After days of figuring out how to use Secrets as an environmental variable, I figured out how to reference it in my nodejs application!

Before I was doing the normal way of calling environmental variables, `process.env.VARIABLE_NAME`, but that did not work for me when I had Secrets as an environment variable. In order to get the value of the variable, I had to do `process.env.ENVIRONMENTAL_VARIABLES_USERNAME` in my Javascript file and that worked for me! Where `ENVIRONMENTAL_VARIABLES` is the `name` and `USERNAME` is the `key`! Refer to my other question for clarification: [Environmental variables returning undefined for Kubernetes deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62394331/environmental-variables-returning-undefined-for-kubernetes-deployment/62395169?noredirect=1#comment110386849_62395169)

Not sure if this will help anyone else but this is how I managed to access my Secrets in my nodejs application!

Answer (score 6):

The environment variable created by secret will read as any other environment variable passed to pod.

So if you create a secret, for example:

```
kubectl create secret generic user --from-literal=username=xyz
```

and pass it to the pod:

```
env:
- name: USERNAME
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: user
      key: username
```

It will be passed to the pod as environment variable. You can check it by executing `printenv USERNAME` in the pod and output will be similar to this:

```
kubectl exec -it secret-env -- printenv USERNAME
xyz
```

[Multiple secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#define-container-environment-variables-with-data-from-multiple-secrets) can be passed to the pod as environment variables.